# GitHub commits not showing up on the calendar using ssh, but files get updated

Tags: linux, github, git-push, git-commit

So I decided to switch and start using ssh key to commit my work on GitHub. However, after I created an ssh key and connected it to GitHub when I push it does not show up on my contributions calendar. But it does the push because I can see the changes on the repository on GitHub. Also when I check my settings and under ssh key it tells me that it was used in the past day, but still no commits on the calendar.

After it did not work with ssh key, I tied going back to https link, but now it does not work that way either. I am using the Virtual Box and I am running the Slackware machine on it, where I do all of my development. Only that machine has the problem I described above.

I tried finding the solution, but it seems people did not have this problem as I hoped.  Can you explain what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: When did you do the commit? Github don't take the push date, It take your commit date.

Comment: @ViníciusFagundes It does not display my commits at all. I do few commits before I push. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YyYXY8md5tbFNudVhLbS12WEU/view?usp=sharing) here you can see that in past 20 days where should be at least 20 to 40 commits you can see only few, and those that you can see are the once that were directly committed on GitHub when I created the projects or edited the Readme

Comment: But can you see on your repo the changes?

Comment: Could I see your repo on github?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in my repo.

Comment: So check your list of commit on `https://github.com/YourGithubAccount/YouGithubRepo/commits/master` this link will list your commits with sorted by dates. (change your account and repo in the link)

Comment: I can see all my commits there. It shows about 25 commits for the past week, but on the contribution calendar it shows only 4

Comment: I got this, just a moment I'm typing the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You had pushed with another author's email.

You have a lot of commit and pushed. But when you did these commits some of them were with another email diff than yours at github. So github cant show as yours on the calendar.

**Follow these [steps to Changing author info history](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) and pushed again to github and the commits will appear on calendar.**

### Edited

The above article is not available any more as @Zahra pointed in the comments. The original anwser is this:

#### Short Answer

Another similar article/script is available in this [repository](https://github.com/pierrechls/changing-author-info).

#### Long Answer

1. Run a git filter-branch:

```bash
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "<antigo_email>" ]; then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<novo_nome>"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<novo_email>"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "<antigo_email>" ]; then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<novo_nome>"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<novo_email>"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Where you should replace <old_email>, <new_name>, <new_email>.

2. Push the corrected history to remote repository:

   git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'

Comment: I solved the problem. Your solution was not the answer, however, it gave me the idea how to solve the problem. What I did is. I went to the home directory and opened .gitconfig file. There I found that under my name tag it stands my email, and that there is no email tag at all. So I created the email tag and added my email there. Also I modified the name tag to match my name on GitHub. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry. But what you did it's not the answer. You solve your problem to prevent doing it. But you didn't change your old commits. However, my answer solves it (old commits) and it was what you asked about.

Comment: @vin The link that you provided is not available any more. can you post the steps to solve the issue?